# Whole list is pressable rather than the button itslef

Tags: swift, swiftui

In the for each loop below, I create a button in the Horizontal stack to delete that object in the array, however rather than just the button being pressable, the whole row is, which is not the design i am looking for. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

```
  struct myView:View{

    @EnvironmentObject var getFood:FoodAddModel
    @EnvironmentObject var person: UserInfoModel


    var unwrappedFoods:[AddedFoods]{
        getFood.foods ?? []
    }
    
    var body: some View{
            List{
            ForEach(Array(unwrappedFoods.enumerated()), id: \.1.id) { (index, obj) in
                HStack{
                HStack{
                            Text(obj.name)
                            Button(action: {
                                getFood.foods?.remove(at: index)
                                person.personCurrentCalorieProgress.calorieProgress +=  obj.totalCals
                            }) {
                                Image(systemName: "minus").foregroundColor(.red)
                            }
                }
                        
            
                }
            }
            }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you have two `HStacks` wrapping your items -- you can probably remove one. Then, what about putting a `Spacer` in between `Text` and `Button`? Does the whole row still seem clickable if you do that?

Answer (score 1):

For solving issue you should use Image instead of button because List make this issue happen! List apply button action for all Row not just for Button!

```
struct myView:View{
    
    @EnvironmentObject var getFood:FoodAddModel
    @EnvironmentObject var person: UserInfoModel
    
    
    var unwrappedFoods:[AddedFoods]{
        getFood.foods ?? []
    }
    
    var body: some View{
        List{
            ForEach(Array(unwrappedFoods.enumerated()), id: \.1.id) { (index, obj) in

                HStack{
                    
                      Text(obj.name)
                        
                      Spacer()
                        
                      Image(systemName: "minus")
                            .frame(width: 40, height: 40, alignment: .center)   // <<: Here 
                            .background(Color.white)        // <<: Here 
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                            .onTapGesture {                 // <<: Here
                            
                                getFood.foods?.remove(at: index)
                                person.personCurrentCalorieProgress.calorieProgress +=  obj.totalCals
     
                            }
                    }
                    
                    
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't try this right now, but was it necessary to materialize this array here: `Array(unwrappedFoods.enumerated())`

Comment: I Just solved the issue he asked, nothing more! maybe he needs in some codes that we do not know,

Comment: They both worked fine, however the press on the minus image has to be so close, it would be an issue for the user. Is there some sort of attribute which makes the space of the pressable area surround the image?

Comment: I would clean that up, if it's possible

Comment: @Matthew: I gave a frame and then a color to background, to make more tappable!

Comment: @Matthew: you can play with that frame size as you like, I used 40X40, you can use 30X30 or what ever you like.

Comment: Using the frame does work well, however I opted to just choose the minus.square.fill as the image, looks and works a whole lot better :) @swiftPunk

Answer (score 0):

`List` seems to behave oddly with buttons, as a workaround you can use **buttonStyle** modifier with value `plainButtonStyle()`

```
import SwiftUI

struct myView:View{
    var body: some View{
        List{
            ForEach(0..<5) { (index) in
             
                HStack{
                    Text("\(index)")
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: {
                        print("foo")
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "minus").foregroundColor(.red)
                    }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```